# Equivalent of fgets in Java

Tags: java, matlab

I wrote a serial communication program in MATLAB and now want to translate it in Java. I have translated the rest of the code but failed with this part:

```
fprintf(s,'C');
x = fgets(s);
```

where x is the response I would like to get from a serial device and
      s is my serial object

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: How do you access that serial device from Java?

Comment: I don't know MATLAB but if you explain what the above code does I cna try to help. I am adding matlab tag so people will know they can help you.

Comment: Here is my full code in Java (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749274/instream-read-in-serial-communications)

Comment: With reference to my code, a need a fix with this part:  try {
       outStream.write('C');
       outStream.write('\r');

       ch = inStream.read();

    } catch(IOException e) {
      //System.out.println(e); 
    }

Comment: Hown is the response string formatted?  Right now you only read one byte.  You probably need to get several, and make them into either a string or a double

Comment: I think it's formatted as a string (for example: 12.34)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a Scanner on your input stream, for example:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //standard input stream
String x = scan.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that `BufferedReader.readLine` would be the java equivalent of `fgets`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()